# Как постепенно добавлять текст в виджет?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как постепенно добавлять текст в виджет? Пример:

```
from tkinter import tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text='Stroka 1')
label.grid()
time.sleep(1)

label = tk.Label(root, text='Stroka 2')
label.grid()
time.sleep(1)

root.mainloop()
```

Я понимаю, что на самом деле он добавляет через каждую секунду строки, но показывает только когда доходит до root.mainloop(). Подскажите как реализовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С помощью метода `root.after` можно задавать выполнение функции через определенный промежуток времени:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text="Some text")
label.grid()

def timer(i=1):
    label['text'] += '\n{}'.format(i)
    root.after(1000, timer, i+1)  # выполнить функцию timer через 1000 мс с параметром i+1

timer()

root.mainloop()
```

Третий параметра в `after` не обязательный, но его удобно использовать например для создания счетчика без глобальных переменных. В упрощенном варианте без дополнительного параметра будет выглядеть так:

```
...
def timer():
    label['text'] += '.'
    root.after(5000, timer)  # выполнить функцию timer через 5000 мс

timer()
...
```

Альтернативный вариант - делать паузу через `sleep`, после каждой паузы делать `root.update()`. Для больших интервалов времени (больше 0.5 - 1 секунд) лучше так не делать, потому что во время паузы окно будет подвисать (не реагировать на действия пользователя, не перерисовываться). В первом варианте таких недостатков нет.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root, text="Some text")
label.grid()

for i in range(10):
    label['text'] += '\n{}'.format(i)
    root.update()
    time.sleep(0.2)  # пауза 0.2 сек

root.mainloop()
```